# shellscript - for loop - grep mail id according to user input from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email, loops

I am having user id's and equivalent mail ids in file. according to user input ( i.e, we will give input as "apple") it should grep only mail id (only apple@gmail.com) and stored in email=$(...)

in-between user ids & mail ids have one space gap in file

*mail id's in file*

```
user_id's   mail_id's

apple apple@gmail.com
mango 123@ymail.com
cat cat@hotmail.com
etc...
```

*sample*

```
email=$(....)

msg= dont run jobs in login node

echo -e "$msg" |mail -s "RAM limit exceeded in iitmlogin4" "$email"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can use `awk`:

```
# userid to search
userid="apple"

email=$(awk -v u="$userid" '$1 == u {print $1}' mail.file)

msg='dont run jobs in login node'

echo -e "$msg" | mail -s "RAM limit exceeded in iitmlogin4" "$email"
```

Answer (score 0):

why not a function?

```
email(){
  userid=$1
  awk "/^$userid / { print \$2; }"
}
```

now to use it just do:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo 
apple apple@gmail.com
mango 123@ymail.com
cat cat@hotmail.com
$ email apple < /tmp/foo 
apple@gmail.com
```

from there it's all simple:

```
$ apple_mail=$(email apple < /tmp/foo )
$ echo $apple_mail 
apple@gmail.com
```